# Handle too many textures Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, sprite, texture-atlas

At present one of my quiz game require, many images of flowers based on questions asked.
I can say total 250+ images with resolution of 512x435 each.
Plus other games textures get loaded at a time.

So when game screen get opened which showing all these images, its on the spot get crashed.
I am testing this on iPhone devices. So how to handle these many textures? I was stuck in this point.

Here is overview of flowers textures.

[image]

I was displaying all these in grid view so in one scrollable screen all get displayed.
Now I hope, you understand my side point of view.

Comment: Normally for this many textures you use texture mapping, also since you wont use 512x435 sizze for apple device you can lower their quality considerably and they wont each as much RAM, which is most likely the reason of your crush, since you were trying to load too many objects and overflowed the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the amount of these images that are loaded at once, try keeping most of those images rendering components disabled using some sort of managing script when you are not seeing them, rather than simply putting them off camera and try to moderate the amount that are rendered at once. If this does not work the problem might be that the total size of the images is bigger then the amount of ram your device has. Even the IPhone X has only 3GB of ram, check if your images in total are bigger than or close to the 1GB-3GB range, unity remote 5 is probably storing these images in ram or temporary memory. It is always a good idea to try to compress your images when working with a mobile device anyway, try to put them into a texture atlas or lower the quality of them until the iphone can handle it, you should never rely on mobile devices to render tons of images at once.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. That's a lot of flowers....
Okay if you need all of those textures, and you're only displaying them in the editor, I'd group them into folders.

Even if you sort the blue from the red..... etc just human readable directories it will help out a lot as you won't load ALL of your images at once.

If you are loading all of those textures at runtime, which I don't think you would as unity optimizes your built executable, I would recommend against loading all of the images at once because you will use a lot of RAM, especially if those images are 512px or larger.

Comment: Just sort the flowers into groups of say, 25 or so into separate folders. If you are on a low end PC it will speed up loading times when you're navigating your project and don't have to load 250+ textures in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

With in the application you could split them into 25 at a time on the screen and you could swipe to the right to go to the next 25 or swipe back to the previous. This is how i solved a similar problem in unity a while back.